# Stack gives 'dyld: malformed mach-o'

Tags: cabal-install, haskell-stack

When I attempt to run stack, for example even just `stack --version`, I get

```
dyld: malformed mach-o: load commands size (38712) > 32768
```

What can I do to fix this. This started appearing after some recent updates to Homebrew.

Comment: `brew reinstall haskell-stack` now works

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you've upgraded to macOS Sierra, because that message looks like you're hitting a new limit in its dynamic linker.  Might be that your `stack` executable is dynamically linked with all the Haskell libraries it uses, which is known to exceed the new limit.  You might try downloading the `osx` binary from [the Stack releases page](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases), which I've heard reports of working on Sierra (it's only dynamically linked to system libraries, but statically linked with Haskell libraries, so shouldn't hit the limit just to run).  Note that you may still have trouble *building* projects with a large number of dependencies, and so far we do not have a workaround for that yet.

Related: [Stack issue #2577](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2577), and [GHC issue #12479](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12479).

Comment: Is there a way to get `cabal update` or `cabal install` to install versions that don't run into this limitation? As it is, what happens is that when I do regular maintenance by running `cabal update`, I get this sort of issue for other packages as well, and my Haskell system is slowly unravelling as a result.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue when I upgraded to macOS Sierra, I was able to run Stack commands again by installing the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/). The Stack tools included in the package seem to work.